# Associate an IP address list with the existing subnet and site

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, subnet, sites

I have a list IP Address and I need to associate for each IP Address of this list the site and subnet.
I have 5203 IP Address and it's too much to verify one by one; maybe someone could help me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much information as @boxdog said.
I am guessing that you are using DHCP and you want to query the scopes and the IPs that are leased.

```
$scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName "DHCP-Server"
foreach($scope in $scopes)
{
    write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "The current scope name is: " -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $scope.name 
    $lease = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeId -ComputerName "DHCP-Server"
    $lease

}
```

If not then please provide more information about what you want to do. Also a script that you already wrote can be helpful.

Comment: Ok I understand SteTheo. So, we have in a txt file, a list of IP Address. I am asked me to create file csv with list of IP Address with the correspondante of Subnets and Sites Active Directory in our forest.

Comment: You mean something like that:
`$IPAdd = Get-Content "path of the txt file, e.g. c:\system\IPaddress.txt"
ForEach ($IP in $IPAdd){
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -IPAddress $IP  -ComputerName "DHCPServer Name" | Format-Table -AutoSize
}`

Comment: Thank you StefTheo but I need to check on site and service Active Directory because in this infrastructure, DHCP is managing by the equipment network.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. And what info you are going to get from AD Sites and Services. Maybe ping -a IP will return you some DNS names if those are registered in the DNS. If you can share more information maybe I can help you.